# Don't understand what the roots of $t^6-8$ are

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I am ultimately asked to find the splitting field of the said polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$. So I must find the roots first and honestly

> $t^6-8=(t^2-2)(t^4+2t^2+4)$ So at least two of my solutions are $\pm \sqrt{2}$. Now $(t^4+2t^2+4)$ is the pain; using quadratic formula gives $t^2=-1 \pm i \sqrt{3}$. Then $t=\pm \sqrt{-1 \pm i \sqrt{3}}$  which looks nasty.

Now, the solution alleges that

> $\xi=e^{2\pi i/6}=1+\omega$ (where $\omega$, following Ian Stewart's notation which my lectures are based on, is the third root of unity) then roots are $\pm \sqrt{2}\xi^k$ for $k=0,1,2$.

I see it gives $\pm \sqrt{2}$ when $k=0$, but otherwise, I don't see how it gives $t=\pm \sqrt{-1 \pm i \sqrt{3}}$ for $k=1,2$. How are these solutions to $(t^4+2t^2+4)$ ?

Comment: Write your complex points inside the root using polar coordinates, then take the root and you will find the solution claimed by the author (which of course is much more elegant and fast)

Comment: Note that $\xi^2=\omega=\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}$.

Comment: @b00nheT Thanks, I do indeed get $t=\pm (\cos{2\pi/6}+i\sin{2\pi/6})$ for my solution $t$, but then, what I still don't undestand is why it's presented in the solutions as $\pm \sqrt{2} \xi$. The $\sqrt{2}$ there is necessary for $k=0$ but when $k=1,2$, my solution  $\pm (\cos{2\pi/6}+i\sin{2\pi/6})$ should just be $\xi$ not $\sqrt{2} \xi$. Am I wrong?

Comment: $\xi$ is wrong, because $\xi^6=1\neq 8$.

Comment: exactly. You most definitely need the $\sqrt{2}$ to get the right module... double check your calculations

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it; We're focusing on $t^4+2t^2+4$ right. So, I get $t^2=-1+i \sqrt{3}$. Which, in polar coordinates, is $t^2=\cos( 2\pi/3) \pm i \sin{2 \pi/3}$. Using De Moivre, $(t^2)^{1/2}=t=\cos{2 \pi/6}\pm i \sin{2 \pi/6}$. Actually, I should be getting $4$ solutions, so I presume it's $t=\pm (\cos{2 \pi/6}\pm i \sin{2 \pi/6})$. Then, since $\xi= \cos{2 \pi/6}+i\sin{2\pi/6}$, isn't that a root for $t^4+2t^2+4$..? I am confused...But then I do need the root $2$ because as pointed out, I need it to be $8$ when powered to $6$. But calculation wise, I do't get $\sqrt{2}$...

Comment: oh nvm, i got it now, thanks!